# Pass URL from ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview

I have a ViewController1 with 2 buttons. And a second ViewController2 whith a UIWebView.

What I´m trying to do:

1- when i click Button1 in ViewController1 it goes to UIWebView in ViewController(2) and open @"www.google.com".

2 - When I click Button2 in ViewController1 it goes to the same UIWebView in ViewController2 and open @"www.apple.com".

How can I pass the URL from the button1 & 2 to the UIWebView in ViewController2?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Have a property on the second UIViewController (subclass) of the form

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *url;
```

When the button is pressed, set this as appropriate, then push the UIViewController onto the UINavigationController.

In the second UIViewController's viewDidLoad method, instruct the UIWebView to open `self.url`.

Comment: I just want to add that if you're using storyboard segues you should implement `prepareForSegue:` method and set there the value for the property on the UIViewController that is going to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have one action that's triggered by both buttons, you'd do something like:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPushed:(UIButton*)sender
{
    ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    switch (sender.tag) {
        case 1:  // button one tapped
            vc2.url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"url for button 1 here";
            break;
        case 2:  // button one tapped
            vc2.url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"url for button 2 here";
            break;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
}
```

As you can see, the idea is to have the first view controller pass along whatever information the second view controller needs when it creates the second view controller.

Comment: Hi Caleb, thanks for your help. Could you please verify this print screen? I have a few errors. Thanks

Comment: Your `sender` parameter is type `id`, which can point to any object. If you don't want the compiler to complain, make sure it's a type that has a `tag` property, like UIView* or UIButton*. Also, you seem to be short at least one curly close bracket.

Comment: Hi Caleb.How are you?    Could you please help me a lit bit more? i got two erros. One that says that there no method urlWithString and another that says that property url was not found in ViewController2, but is there...I will send four prints from the four files. If you dont mind and take a look. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry -- I should have been a little more clear. Often when people answer questions like yours, code is typed directly into SO, especially when the author doesn't have a compiler handy. I like to test answers when I can, but in this case I didn't, so there are a few minor errors. You can discover the answers for yourself by checking the documentation for the affected classes: the method to create an URL from a string is called `URLWithString:` rather than `urlWithString:`, and the method for pushing a new controller is `-pushViewController:animated:`.